# #! fallback for POST requests

Tags: angularjs, http

I am using angular 1.2

I have configured

```
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

When using IE8 and IE9 I got two requests:

1. POST /base/action
2. GET /base/#!/action

So parameters from the first post are tragically lost...

The simple solution is just to send POST /base/#!/action on ie8 and 9 (so there is no redirection), but since this is partially out of our control.

I was wondering if there is a solution to send a POST for the request 2., even if some server side processing (for example to expose in JS POST data) is needed.

**EDIT:**

Some more details on the scenario. I am talking about the first request we get to our site. The request is done by a third party, and it must be done using POST. As a result the user should see the first page of our angular application. I am not talking about a request made with $http, and this is not a call to an API. The expected result is an HTML page. The POST request is coming from another page, using "classical" form submit method.

Comment: The `#!` should have nothing to do with your API calls (such as `POST`). They're for your browser and view. So i'm a little confused by your question.

Comment: The first call to our site is a POST, and we can do nothing to change that.

Comment: Ok, but the post is to your server, not to your client-side code.

Comment: So the idea would be that the first POST request could return some JS that redirects to the real Angular app?

Comment: Hard to say, as I don't know your scenario or app, though that sounds more applicable.

Comment: The parameters from the first post don't have to be lost, they can be saved to any number of variables... you can save data to window variables, scope variables, or localStorage. Not all of these would be a best practice, but they do work. Now, your question is not very clears as to what you are asking. Can you elaborate on it? Anything being done via POST would be done by $http service in angular, so you wouldn't be able to send it to #!/action unless your server has that mapping, because #! is being used by angular, not by your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use fallback mode #! on all the borwsers, so I do not have this issue and I keep things simple.